# Android device admin home directory access

Tags: android

I am writing an application  for my phone in which I would like to be able to read and write to the android equivalent of my /home or /home/user  folder (similar to a file manager) which I believe is /data or /data/data. I have been reading up on device admin and a lot of the posts on it here, and  I granted my app device admin privilages and got access denied to /data and /data/data.

What are the read and write privalages of device admin ? In addition, if the folders I specified are not the /home or /home/user folders what is the /home folder  or /home/user and can a device admin read and write to either or do I need my device to be rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not what device admin does.  Device admin and device owner (which is like a super admin) allow you to set the policy of the device-  prevent the user from installing apps, or uninstalling them, or changing the network, or a dozen other things.  Or wipe the device.  Its meant for enterprise control of remote devices.

For example I'm currently writing a kiosk app.  I want to lock it down so that only the 1 app can be run.  I use device owner powers to prevent a dozen things the user could otherwise do.

Comment: So I assume what this also implies is that no app can read and write to the user home folder unless it's root? How do file managers do it though ?

Comment: What do you mean by the /home directory?  By default there is none on Android.  adb shell into an emulator (or phone) and you won't see one even with root.  Instead each app has its own private directory in /data/data/appname.  You're thinking too much linux here.  AS for accessing those folders, you need root for any except your own.

Comment: I guess what I was thinking of was the local storage that appears in the android file managers... which I thought acted as a " user home" directory and didn't seem application specific, because the file managers can  look at the local storage of other apps. I assume now that this is not accessing each apps /data/data/app name since u said those directories are  private to the app and that local storage is different ?

Comment: No.  Its probably looking at the external storage root, or maybe the documents folder inside there.  There are shared directories on the external storage (which isn't always external anymore) that all apps can access.